# How do I change the label class for a radio button in Symfony2.8/Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

So I have these 2 codes:

**my PHP code**

```
$builder
->setMethod("GET")
->add(
    "type"
    , "choice"
    , array(
        "choices" => array("student"=>"Student ID",  "hr"=>"HR number")
        , "expanded" => true
        , "label_attr" => array(
                "class" => "myclasshere"
        )
        , "multiple" => false
        , "required" => false
    )
```

**my twig template:**

```
{{ form_label(form.type[0]) }}
```

My problem is that no class is being applied to the label.

I also tried:

```
{{ form_label(form.type[0], {"label_attr":{"class":"myclasshere"}}) }}
```

And this gave an error.

Any ideas how it is done? My alternative is to write the label tags myself instead of using Twig.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter should be the label text, or null.

```
{{ form_label(form.type[0], null, {"label_attr":{"class":"myclasshere"}}) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The class is an attribute of the label tag, so in Twig it should be written in the "attr" array like this:

```
{{ form_label(form.type[0], {"attr":{"class":"myclasshere"}}) }}
```